# How to remove debug symbols from a WebAssembly file

Tags: webassembly, emscripten

I was looking at the browser console while running a wasm program. The warnings emitted shows that the program knows a whole lot about the source. I would like to remove all these and have a small, succinct binary.

So given a file file.wasm, how do I easily strip off all these debug symbols?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/Debugging.html):

> Emcc strips out most of the debug information from optimized builds by default. Optimisation levels -O1 and above remove LLVM debug information, and also disable runtime ASSERTIONS checks. From optimization level -O2 the code is minified by the Closure Compiler and becomes virtually unreadable.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess maybe the file paths of my source included along with the wasm file, might just be bloat since I used optimization above -O1